# Highlight (bold font) row in asp:Repeater with timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, repeater, highlight

I have a list of activities that is displayed with a Repeater. I already use Timers to display these, so the Timer isn't the problem. It's the code that i have to put into the `Timer_tick` method.

The "highlight-Timer" is supposed to highlight the items/rows one at a time, and then I want to display some info related to the highlighted row.

If it's easier with another control that's no problem. I doesn't have to be a Repeater. I just use it because of the styling-possibilities (it isn't displayed in just one line, but with several line-breaks etc.)

As requested:

(Repeater)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="divActivity" runat="server">
            <span style="font-size:30px;">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "act_headline") %>
            </span>
            <br />
            <img alt="mapIcon" src="../img/mapIcon.gif" height="15px" width="15px" style="position:absolute;" />
            <span style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; margin-left:23px;">    
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "act_place") %>
            </span>
            <img alt="watchIcon" src="../img/watchIcon.png" height="15px" width="15px" style="position:absolute;" /> 
            <span style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; margin-left:23px;">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "act_start") %> - <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "act_end") %>
            </span>
            <br />
            <div style="word-wrap: break-word; width:1000px; margin-top:20px; padding:0;">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "act_text") %>
            </div>
            <br />
                <img alt="infoIcon" src="../img/infoIcon.png" height="15px" width="15px" style="position:absolute;" />
            <span style="font-size:12px; margin-left:23px;"><a target="_blank" href="http://<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "act_info") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "act_info") %></a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I don't have anything in the the Timer_tick-event, as i've tried several things and the deleted it after it failed. Hope it's enough.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've added the code of the Repeater to the main post.

Comment: If I understand you well you're trying to highlight one item at a time?

Comment: Exacly! First row1, then row2 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set a special CSS class to the highlighted item by using something like this in the tick event handler by looping over the `Repeater.Items` collection.

Something like this (untested):

```
int currentHighlight = -1;
int nextHighlight = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    HtmlControl htmlDiv = (HtmlControl)Repeater1.Controls[i].Controls[1];

    if (htmlDiv.Attributes["class"] != null)
    {
        if (htmlDiv.Attributes["class"].Contains("highlighted")) // this is the currently highlighted item
        {
            // record currently highlighted item index
            currentHighlight = i;

            // remove highlight
            htmlDiv.Attributes["class"].Replace("highlighted", "");
            htmlDiv.Attributes["class"].Trim();
        }
    }
}

if ((currentHighlight == -1) || (currentHighlight == Repeater1.Items.Count))
{
    // handle first Item highlighting
    nextHighlight = 1;
}
else
{
    // handle standard case
    nextHighlight = currentHighlight + 1;
}

// highlight next item
((HtmlControl)Repeater1.Controls[nextHighlight].Controls[1]).Attributes["class"] += " highlighted";
```

Then you can use the `highlighted` CSS class to handle styling (the bold font you mention) as well as some special behavior in JavaScript or jQuery for example.

BTW, you can do any other operation on the `RepeaterItem` object once you get which one is currently highlighted.

Comment: I'm testing it now, but I get the error that RepeaterItem doesn't contain a definition for CssClass?

Comment: Sorry for that, you will have to use the `HtmlControl` class for that. I've edited the code above...

Comment: I've tried that, but the problem is, that the id of the div (divActivity) changes for each row, for them to be unique.

When i used the "auto-generated" id, it didn't work. I did when i tried it on a "static" div-id, though. How would you get the "auto-generated" id? Maybe you know a way of getting it to work..

Comment: Repeater1_divActivity_# WHERE # is 0 for first, 1 for second row etc. (First row: Repeater1_divActivity_0).

I get the value with:
Repeater1.Controls[<int that increments>].Controls[1].ClientID;

Comment: It gives me an error (the object reference not set to an instance of an object) at this line (if (htmlDiv.Attributes["class"].Contains("highlighted"))). I checked to see if it actually returned the divs and it did (Repeater1.Controls[i].Controls[1].ClientID;) so that ain't the problem.

Comment: You will have to check that the `class` attribute is not `null`. I've edited the example but it remains untested though.

Comment: And now it works! I'll have to make some minor adjustments, but it does make the text bold. Thank you so much!

Comment: I believe i've done that now? I've never posted inhere before.